# Compute values from dropdown to create a function for calculate prices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to write the calcTotal function but I'm not sure how I would differentiate the selected pizza and the number of pizza requested. I want to assign the following prices to each pizza (Cheese $6, Pepperoni $8, Veggie $8, Hawaiian $9, Supreme $10). I think I declared the proper variables and called by the correct Id but then I'm not sure where to go next.

EDIT: I've worked on the calcTotal function but my alert isn't displaying and I'm not sure if I'm calling things properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <form>
      <h2>Customer Information</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First and Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="phone" class="col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>Delivery Address</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Address" class="col-form-label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="1234 Main St">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Address2" class="col-form-label">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="City" class="col-form-label">City</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="Springfield">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="State" class="col-form-label">State</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="MO">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="inputZip" class="col-form-label">Zip</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="65806">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>Order Details</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="pizzaChoice" class="col-form-label">Choose a Pizza Type</label>
          <select id="pizzaChoice"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="orderAmount" class="col-form-label">How Hungry Are You?</label>
          <select id="orderAmount"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="submit" onclick="calcTotal()">Place Order</button>
    </form>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      var order = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
      select = document.getElementById('orderAmount');
      for(quant in order) {
        select.add(new Option(order[quant], quant));
      };
      var pizzaTypes = ['Cheese', 'Pepperoni', 'Veggie', 'Hawaiian', 'Supreme'],
      select = document.getElementById('pizzaChoice');
      for(pizzas in pizzaTypes) {
        select.add(new Option(pizzaTypes[pizzas], pizzas));
      };
      </script>
      <script>
      function calcTotal() {
          var cusName = document.getElementById("name").value;
          var phoneNum = document.getElementById("phone").value;
          var pizzasOdered = document.getElementById("orderAmount").value;
          var orderedPizzaType = document.getElementById("pizzaChoice");
          if (orderedPizzaType = pizzaTypes[0]) {
              itemTotal = 7.00;
              else if (orderedPizzaType = pizzaTypes[1]) {
                itemTotal = 8.00;
              }
              else if (orderedPizzaType = pizzaTypes[2]) {
                itemTotal = 8.50;
              }
              else if (orderedPizzaType = pizzaTypes[3]) {
                itemTotal = 9.50;
              }
              else if (orderedPizzaType = pizzaTypes[4]) {
                itemTotal = 10.00;
              }
          }
          var subTotal = itemTotal * pizzasOdered;
          var salesTaxRate = 0.076;
          var salesTax = (itemTotal * salesTaxRate);
          var orderTotal = subTotal + (subTotal * salesTaxRate);
          alert("Thank you for your order " + cusName + "! If we have any issues we'll call you at " + phoneNum + "<br>" +
                     "Here's your oder summary: " + pizzasOdered + orderedPizzaType + "pizzas were ordered." +
                     "Pizza Price: $" + itemTotal + "<br>" +
                     "Sub Total: $" + subTotal + "<br>" +
                     "Sales Tax: $" + salesTax + "<br>" +
                     "Total Due: $" + orderTotal);
      }
      document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
      document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", clearForm, true);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it misbehaving?  What happens when you try it?  What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: @theGleep I don't really know how I should assign the dollar value you to each pizza type so I can calculate the total

Comment: Ah - I guess I didn't read carefully enough.  Since I don't see anywhere that you declare the dollar amounts, I'm guessing that's what you're wanting help with.  You could create another array that parallels pizza types to give you a list of prices.  Or you could declare pizzaTypes as an array of objects rather than an array of strings.

Comment: @theGleep so if I said pizzaTypes[0] that would return Cheese pizza, correct? My thought process would be to declare the prices for each pizza in the calcTotal function then based of the pizzaTypes selection and the number they want to order, I would do the arithmetic. I'm just unsure how to write this.

Comment: You could do that ... not an approach I had considered, but would work.  A simple collection of "if" statements would do: `if (selectedPizza == 'cheese') {} elseif ... `  I'm guessing you're learning (possibly this is a school assignment?) - so in the future you will learn more complicated techniques.  For now, your solution will work fine.  Go with what you know, when you *know* it, move on to "better ways".

Comment: @theGleep thanks for your help! I was writing the way I had in my previous comment then stopped midway with a "wow you're an idiot" moment and started doing the if else if statements thinking that might work and you just confirmed that!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll add an actual answer that gives other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For programmers learning how to do something like this, the first approach is usually just a bunch of `if` or `if/else` statements.

The second approach teaches how to use a `switch` statement, now that if/else chains are understood; use a `switch` statement.

The third approach is often to have parallel arrays - one for pizzas and one for prices.  Instead of using the pizza name, the index of the selected pizza is used, which is also the index to the price for the pizza.  This approach is troublesome, because future development requires maintaining two lists, and it's easy to forget to do that.  (Like if you re-arrange the pizzas, or add a new one, you have to do the same for the prices)

For a quick-and-dirty solution, I would probably use a `dictionary` (aka hashtable).  The key in the dictionary would be the pizza name, and the price would be the dictionary value.  Or I might create an object that completely describes the pizza, including price ... but that's a pretty advanced approach for someone just learning :)

The last approach (I can think of that doesn't involve databases) is to create an array of pizza description objects.

See how much you have to look forward to as you get into programming!?!  :)

Have fun!

Comment: I've edited my original question with my updated code and functions. My alert isn't being displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: I'd recommend using the debugger - F12 in your browser.  Set a breakpoint in the code and run it ... It's the easiest way to figure out for yourself what is going wrong.

Comment: OK, I will give a hint ... check your block openings and closings ... look for mis-aligned `{...}`

Comment: Thanks! { = the hide and seek champion of the world!